# Yii showing user type in view using user identity object

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I need to show the type of user in the view in `protected/views/layouts/main.php`.

But I am getting this error:

```
"CException" ."Property "CWebUser.type" is not defined."
```

I am unable to get rid of this error , how to resolve this issue?

I am using this line of code to display the type of user

```
array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->type.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 
'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
```

I tried by using  user->user_type   also but not working

My code for the `UserIdentity class`

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;


    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'email'=>$this->username));
        if ($user === null) {

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if ($user->pass !==
        hash_hmac('sha256', $this->password,
                Yii::app()->params['encryptionKey']) ) {

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else { 
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            $this->setState('type', $user->user_type);
            $this->setState('id', $user->id);
            $this->_id = $user->id;

        }
        return !$this->errorCode;

    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;

    }

}
```

Also since I am using Role based access control I have changed the code in user.php for assigning roles to users

My code to assign users type.

```
public function afterSave() {
        if (!Yii::app()->authManager->isAssigned(
                $this->type,$this->id)) {
            Yii::app()->authManager->assign($this->type,
            $this->id);
        }
        return parent::afterSave();
        }
```

And I have used this code in my  SiteController for assigning roles to users

```
$auth->assign($user->type,$user->id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I;m right in what's happening, there may be times when you're not logged in that Yii is trying to access the user settings. As you're not logged in you can't access them, hence the error. So in the label, check that user isset()

```
'label' => (isset(Yii::app()->user->type) ? Yii::app()->user->type : '')
```